# Cassandra - Exception (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError) encountered during startup: Can't find dependent libraries( jna626409071981896679.dll)

Tags: java, cassandra

I am trying to install Cassandra 3.11.8 on Windows 10 Pro OS 8GB RAM machine. I have installed JDK 1.8.0u271 and Python 2.7.17 on the same.

I have added the system variables path for the JDK, Python, and Cassandra.

I have unzipped the Cassandra 3.11.8 file and added it under the c drive.

To start the Cassandra, I have typed the command `cassandra` at the bin location of the Cassandra file in the command prompt ( Opened the command prompt by clicking 'Run as administrator).

I am getting the following exception.

```
C:\>cd apache-cassandra-3.11.8

C:\apache-cassandra-3.11.8>cassandra
Detected powershell execution permissions.  Running with enhanced startup scripts.
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

    WARNING!  Automatic page file configuration detected.
    It is recommended that you disable swap when running Cassandra
    for performance and stability reasons.

*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

    WARNING! Detected a power profile other than High Performance.
    Performance of this node will suffer.
    Modify conf\cassandra.env.ps1 to suppress this warning.

*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

C:\apache-cassandra-3.11.8>CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/Columns$Serializer.deserializeLargeSubset (Lorg/apache/cassandra/io/util/DataInputPlus;Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;I)Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/Columns$Serializer.serializeLargeSubset (Ljava/util/Collection;ILorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;ILorg/apache/cassandra/io/util/DataOutputPlus;)V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/Columns$Serializer.serializeLargeSubsetSize (Ljava/util/Collection;ILorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;I)I
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/commitlog/AbstractCommitLogSegmentManager.advanceAllocatingFrom (Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/commitlog/CommitLogSegment;)V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/transform/BaseIterator.tryGetMoreContents ()Z
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/transform/StoppingTransformation.stop ()V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/transform/StoppingTransformation.stopInPartition ()V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.doFlush (I)V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.writeExcessSlow ()V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.writeSlow (JI)VCompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/RebufferingInputStream.readPrimitiveSlowly (I)J
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/db/rows/UnfilteredSerializer.serializeRowBody (Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/rows/Row;ILorg/apache/cassandra/db/SerializationHeader;Lorg/apache/cassandra/io/util/DataOutputPlus;)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/Memory.checkBounds (JJ)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/SafeMemory.checkBounds (JJ)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering.selectBoundary (Lorg/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering/Op;II)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering.strictnessOfLessThan (Lorg/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering/Op;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/BloomFilter.indexes (Lorg/apache/cassandra/utils/IFilter/FilterKey;)[J
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/BloomFilter.setIndexes (JJIJ[J)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compare (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;[B)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compare ([BLjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compareUnsigned (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;JILjava/lang/Object;JI)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;JILjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/vint/VIntCoding.encodeVInt (JI)[B
INFO  [main] 2020-11-08 21:48:47,508 YamlConfigurationLoader.java:89 - Configuration location: file:/C:/apache-cassandra-3.11.8/conf/cassandra.yaml
INFO  [main] 2020-11-08 21:48:48,541 Config.java:536 - Node configuration:[allocate_tokens_for_keyspace=null; authenticator=AllowAllAuthenticator; authorizer=AllowAllAuthorizer; auto_bootstrap=true; auto_snapshot=true; back_pressure_enabled=false; back_pressure_strategy=org.apache.cassandra.net.RateBasedBackPressure{high_ratio=0.9, factor=5, flow=FAST}; batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb=50; batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb=5; batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb=1024; broadcast_address=null; broadcast_rpc_address=null; buffer_pool_use_heap_if_exhausted=true; cas_contention_timeout_in_ms=1000; cdc_enabled=false; cdc_free_space_check_interval_ms=250; cdc_raw_directory=null; cdc_total_space_in_mb=0; check_for_duplicate_rows_during_compaction=true; check_for_duplicate_rows_during_reads=true; client_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; cluster_name=Test Cluster; column_index_cache_size_in_kb=2; column_index_size_in_kb=64; commit_failure_policy=stop; commitlog_compression=null; commitlog_directory=null; commitlog_max_compression_buffers_in_pool=3; commitlog_periodic_queue_size=-1; commitlog_segment_size_in_mb=32; commitlog_sync=periodic; commitlog_sync_batch_window_in_ms=NaN; commitlog_sync_period_in_ms=10000; commitlog_total_space_in_mb=null; compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb=100; compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec=16; concurrent_compactors=null; concurrent_counter_writes=32; concurrent_materialized_view_writes=32; concurrent_reads=32; concurrent_replicates=null; concurrent_writes=32; counter_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; counter_cache_save_period=7200; counter_cache_size_in_mb=null; counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; credentials_cache_max_entries=1000; credentials_update_interval_in_ms=-1; credentials_validity_in_ms=2000; cross_node_timeout=false; data_file_directories=[Ljava.lang.String;@48f2bd5b; disk_access_mode=auto; disk_failure_policy=stop; disk_optimization_estimate_percentile=0.95; disk_optimization_page_cross_chance=0.1; disk_optimization_strategy=ssd; dynamic_snitch=true; dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold=0.1; dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms=600000; dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms=100; enable_materialized_views=true; enable_sasi_indexes=true; enable_scripted_user_defined_functions=false; enable_user_defined_functions=false; enable_user_defined_functions_threads=true; encryption_options=null; endpoint_snitch=SimpleSnitch; file_cache_round_up=null; file_cache_size_in_mb=null; gc_log_threshold_in_ms=200; gc_warn_threshold_in_ms=1000; hinted_handoff_disabled_datacenters=[]; hinted_handoff_enabled=true; hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb=1024; hints_compression=null; hints_directory=null; hints_flush_period_in_ms=10000; incremental_backups=false; index_interval=null; index_summary_capacity_in_mb=null; index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes=60; initial_token=null; inter_dc_stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec=200; inter_dc_tcp_nodelay=false; internode_authenticator=null; internode_compression=dc; internode_recv_buff_size_in_bytes=0; internode_send_buff_size_in_bytes=0; key_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; key_cache_save_period=14400; key_cache_size_in_mb=null; listen_address=localhost; listen_interface=null; listen_interface_prefer_ipv6=false; listen_on_broadcast_address=false; max_hint_window_in_ms=10800000; max_hints_delivery_threads=2; max_hints_file_size_in_mb=128; max_mutation_size_in_kb=null; max_streaming_retries=3; max_value_size_in_mb=256; memtable_allocation_type=heap_buffers; memtable_cleanup_threshold=null; memtable_flush_writers=0; memtable_heap_space_in_mb=null; memtable_offheap_space_in_mb=null; min_free_space_per_drive_in_mb=50; native_transport_flush_in_batches_legacy=true; native_transport_max_concurrent_connections=-1; native_transport_max_concurrent_connections_per_ip=-1; native_transport_max_concurrent_requests_in_bytes=-1; native_transport_max_concurrent_requests_in_bytes_per_ip=-1; native_transport_max_frame_size_in_mb=256; native_transport_max_negotiable_protocol_version=-2147483648; native_transport_max_threads=128; native_transport_port=9042; native_transport_port_ssl=null; num_tokens=256; otc_backlog_expiration_interval_ms=200; otc_coalescing_enough_coalesced_messages=8; otc_coalescing_strategy=DISABLED; otc_coalescing_window_us=200; partitioner=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner; permissions_cache_max_entries=1000; permissions_update_interval_in_ms=-1; permissions_validity_in_ms=2000; phi_convict_threshold=8.0; prepared_statements_cache_size_mb=null; range_request_timeout_in_ms=10000; read_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; repair_session_max_tree_depth=18; request_scheduler=org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler; request_scheduler_id=null; request_scheduler_options=null; request_timeout_in_ms=10000; role_manager=CassandraRoleManager; roles_cache_max_entries=1000; roles_update_interval_in_ms=-1; roles_validity_in_ms=2000; row_cache_class_name=org.apache.cassandra.cache.OHCProvider; row_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; row_cache_save_period=0; row_cache_size_in_mb=0; rpc_address=localhost; rpc_interface=null; rpc_interface_prefer_ipv6=false; rpc_keepalive=true; rpc_listen_backlog=50; rpc_max_threads=2147483647; rpc_min_threads=16; rpc_port=9160; rpc_recv_buff_size_in_bytes=null; rpc_send_buff_size_in_bytes=null; rpc_server_type=sync; saved_caches_directory=null; seed_provider=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider{seeds=127.0.0.1}; server_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms=500; snapshot_before_compaction=false; snapshot_on_duplicate_row_detection=false; ssl_storage_port=7001; sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb=50; start_native_transport=true; start_rpc=false; storage_port=7000; stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec=200; streaming_keep_alive_period_in_secs=300; streaming_socket_timeout_in_ms=86400000; thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb=15; thrift_max_message_length_in_mb=16; thrift_prepared_statements_cache_size_mb=null; tombstone_failure_threshold=100000; tombstone_warn_threshold=1000; tracetype_query_ttl=86400; tracetype_repair_ttl=604800; transparent_data_encryption_options=org.apache.cassandra.config.TransparentDataEncryptionOptions@7b2bbc3; trickle_fsync=false; trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb=10240; truncate_request_timeout_in_ms=60000; unlogged_batch_across_partitions_warn_threshold=10; user_defined_function_fail_timeout=1500; user_defined_function_warn_timeout=500; user_function_timeout_policy=die; windows_timer_interval=1; write_request_timeout_in_ms=2000]
INFO  [main] 2020-11-08 21:48:48,544 DatabaseDescriptor.java:381 - DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
INFO  [main] 2020-11-08 21:48:48,547 DatabaseDescriptor.java:439 - Global memtable on-heap threshold is enabled at 118MB
INFO  [main] 2020-11-08 21:48:48,548 DatabaseDescriptor.java:443 - Global memtable off-heap threshold is enabled at 118MB
WARN  [main] 2020-11-08 21:48:48,760 DatabaseDescriptor.java:579 - Only 51.858GiB free across all data volumes. Consider adding more capacity to your cluster or removing obsolete snapshots
INFO  [main] 2020-11-08 21:48:48,799 RateBasedBackPressure.java:123 - Initialized back-pressure with high ratio: 0.9, factor: 5, flow: FAST, window size: 2000.
INFO  [main] 2020-11-08 21:48:48,800 DatabaseDescriptor.java:773 - Back-pressure is disabled with strategy org.apache.cassandra.net.RateBasedBackPressure{high_ratio=0.9, factor=5, flow=FAST}.
Exception (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError) encountered during startup: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\jna-2645995\jna626409071981896679.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\jna-2645995\jna626409071981896679.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1934)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1817)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:810)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:851)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:826)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:140)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WindowsTimer.<clinit>(WindowsTimer.java:35)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:625)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:768)
ERROR [main] 2020-11-08 21:48:48,928 CassandraDaemon.java:785 - Exception encountered during startupjava.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\jna-2645995\jna626409071981896679.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1934) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1817) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:810) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
        at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:851) ~[jna-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2 (b0)]
        at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:826) ~[jna-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2 (b0)]        at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:140) ~[jna-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2 (b0)]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WindowsTimer.<clinit>(WindowsTimer.java:35) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.8.jar:3.11.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:625) [apache-cassandra-3.11.8.jar:3.11.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:768) [apache-cassandra-3.11.8.jar:3.11.8]
```

Please let me know if anyone knows the solution for the same. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The most common cause of this issue is a non-compliant JDK from a vendor. For example, lots of users reported running into this problem with AdoptOpenJDK.

Try installing Java from Oracle or OpenJDK instead and see how you go. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, I have switch to oracle JDK 1.8.0_202 from oracle JDK 1.8.0_271 and the issue got resolved

Comment: I have to change it to jdk1.8.0_181

Answer (score 0):

For me, the same issue was occurring for the embedded Cassandra dependency in the Mac M1, below is the dependency I used.

```
<groupId>org.cassandraunit</groupId>
<artifactId>cassandra-unit</artifactId>
<version>4.3.1.0</version>
```

The above error is fixed when I changed the JDK to **adoptopenjdk-8.jdk** from **azul zulu version 1.8** in **Intellij->File->Project Structure->SDK**.