# Can't start Cassandra on Windows, getting UnsatisfiedLinkError "Can't find dependent libraries"

Tags: cassandra

Java:

```
java version "1.8.0_271"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_271-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.271-b09, mixed mode)
```

Python Version: Python 2.7.18

I wanted to start cassandra but I got this error:

```
na8359801313343189739.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\rambo\AppData\Local\Temp\jna-108279019\jna8359801313343189739.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:851)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:826)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:140)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WindowsTimer.<clinit>(WindowsTimer.java:35)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:630)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:786)
ERROR [main] 2021-06-04 19:01:40,594 CassandraDaemon.java:803 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\rambo\AppData\Local\Temp\jna-108279019\jna8359801313343189739.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
        at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
        at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:851) ~[jna-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2 (b0)]
        at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:826) ~[jna-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2 (b0)]
        at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:140) ~[jna-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2 (b0)]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WindowsTimer.<clinit>(WindowsTimer.java:35) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.10.jar:3.11.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:630) [apache-cassandra-3.11.10.jar:3.11.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:786) [apache-cassandra-3.11.10.jar:3.11.10]
```

i am very thankful for you help!!!

Comment: use docker on windows

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64741348/cassandra-exception-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-encountered-during-startu. Please refer this.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this is usually due to an issue with a Java vendor. For whatever reason, this has come up several times with AdoptOpenJDK.

I suspect AdoptOpenJDK is not TCK-compliant which could account for the errors but I admit I've never used it so I don't really know. I'd recommend using Java from Oracle or OpenJDK instead.

I've also noted that you're running Java 8u271. I've heard reports that updates 261 to 271 have been problematic for some users so I recommend using earlier versions such as Java 8 update 252 or newer versions such as updates 282 or 292.

As a side note, we rarely run tests on Windows (if ever) so I would echo Alex Ott's recommendation to use Docker instead. As an alternative, consider deploying [K8ssandra.io](http://k8ssandra.io/). If you just want to test writing apps on Cassandra, [Astra](http://dtsx.io/3mw14tX) has a free tier you could use. Cheers!